# Can you now obtain different pickups instead of coins in Greed Mode?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

I'm playing some runs in *Greed Mode* after the last update patch and I've noticed something different in the last one.

Accorging to [Rebirth wikia](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Greed_Mode#Arena):

> At the start of each wave, several pennies are dropped on the ground, which Isaac can use in the shop to purchase items and pickups. The more waves that spawn without pressing the red button, the more money will drop.

But in this run I've obtained a couple of chests, keys and even an item instead of the usual coins.

Here you can see an example, a *Stoned Chest* and an item (the empty pedestal was an *X-Ray Vision*) between coins:

[image]

Is this a new feature of the last update? Or is there a new item that turns coins in other pickups?

Comment: Do you remember which character you were playing with? Did you take a screenshot of the items you had equipped?

Comment: @Kappei I was using Lilith. No I don't have the screenshot, but my items were: GB Bug, Spider Mod, Sacrificial Dagger, Lusty Blood, Gnawed Leaf, Juicy Sack, Death's Touch, Gemini, Box, Infestation2 and a couple of other familiars. And of course, Lilith's starting items.

Comment: Did you have Lilith's third starting item equipped?  I think it's unlocked by beating The Chest as her in normal mode.

Comment: @Powerlord I had Box of Friends, Cambion Conception and Incubus. You should have them even if not unlocked. Anyway I've already reached The Chest with Lilith in a previous run.

Comment: @pinckerman Ah, OK, Cambion Conception was the one I was thinking of.  Some people seem to be confused about how it works, so I was wondering if it possibly had any effect here.  I was under the impression that it mainly spawned new familiars, though.

Comment: @Powerlord Yes, it should spawn demonic familiars after taking damage a certain number of times. But I've never activated it.

Comment: You mentioned a couple of other familiars. Is it possible that one of them was the GB Bug? That's the MissingNo thing that bounces around the room.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yes, one of them was GB Bug, it's the first item I've listed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned that you had the GB Bug. According to the website [Platinum God](http://platinumgod.co.uk/), one of its effects is:

> If the GB Bug passes over a consumable, it has a chance to reroll it into another random consumable.

It simply rerolled a couple of your pennies before you collected them.

Comment: Interesting, the wikia says nothing about it. I guess you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the items/boxes dropped from new waves? On common occasions rocks, mushrooms etc. are destroyed by enemies in the room and those have a chance to drop stuff like chests and so on. I have not gotten anything but coins from the waves. Any item- and chestdrops I got were caused by explosions or any other ways that destroy rocks.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. As you can see in my screenshot the chest and the pedestal are aligned with the spawned coins.
Only tinted rocks can drop stuff like chests or pickups, but there were none.